# An conditional Sum of elements in Array

Tags: list-manipulation, conditional

Consider we have:

```
list = {{2, 3}, {3, 30}, {3, 2}, {4, 53}}
```

and we want to compare the first elements and sum the second elements if first elements are similar them we should get a array

```
newlist = {{2, 3}, {3, 32}, {4, 53}}
```

So I did the instruction bellow that did not workout.

```
Table[if[list[[i, 1]] == list[[i + 1, 1]], 
 {list[[i, 1]], list[[i, 2]] + list[[i + 1, 2]]}, 
 {list[[i, 1]], list[[i, 2]]}], {i, Length[list] - 1}]
```

How to work around?

Comment: Use `If` instead of `if`. Also take a look at patterns -- should be able to cope with difficulty.

Answer (score 5):

There are a few approaches to this, e.g.

```
Last@Reap[Sow[#2, #1] & @@@ list, _, {#1, Total@#2} &]
```

or

```
List @@@ Normal[GroupBy[list, First -> Last, Total]]
```

or

```
{1/Length@#, 1} Total[#] & /@ GatherBy[list, First]
```

All yield:

```
{{2, 3}, {3, 32}, {4, 53}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using patterns

```
list = {{2, 3}, {3, 30}, {3, 2}, {4, 53}};

list //. {s___, {a_, x_}, m___, {a_, y_}, e___} :>
  {s, {a, x + y}, m, e}
```

> {{2, 3}, {3, 32}, {4, 53}}